# How do I ensure a bouncing object lands on a scrolling object on the ground (after “X” bounces) where "X" bounces is known in advance?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Please see the demo of what I have at the moment:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zfg3crvoohrrhij/bouncingDemo.mov?dl=0

There is an orange square that should bounce on a green square after the orange square bounces "X" times (where "X" is defined in advance).  For example, after the orange square bounces 2 times, it MUST land on a green square on the 3rd bounce and increase in height again and resume bouncing.

The issue I'm facing is that the orange square doesn't always land on a green square. Sometimes the orange square lands on the green square as expected but other times it lands just before or after it.  I add the green squares (off screen) after a certain number of frames and move them by changing it's "X" co-ordinate every frame.  The orange square is moved by using transitions (rather than by every frame).

What is the best way to guarantee the orange object lands on the green object after every 3 bounces?

Answer (score 0):

Make both the square and platforms position a function of time.

so the plaform position might be :

Xp = velocity * t

Yp = height of platform

the bouncing squares position is more complicated, but the x position is easy

Xb = velocityX * t

Yb is complicated by the bounce, as the discontinuity is hard to express.

If we assume no energy lost per bounce, so each bounce lasts the same time though :

Yb = (initialUpVelocityY * t mod bounceTime) - (0.5 * g * (t mod bouncetime)^2)

now solve for Xp = Xb and Yp = Yb and t= x * bouncetime